# Identifying a communication protocol found on a RJ14 cable

Tags: cables, led-driver, protocol

I have a LED panel controller that can daisy chain with an another led panel controllers using a RJ14 cable to adjust a PWM that dims the panel.
This is what I see on the RJ14 pins. A periodic signal that looks like this:
[image]

Seems to go at 25 MHz or even higher.

Is this a standard protocol, or is it a proprietary thing that needs to be reverse engineered?

By the way, this is the outputted signal when the dimmer is at around 75%

Here you can see the controller with the dimmer on it outputs a PWM to two LED drivers. The ch1 connector is to receive data from a master controller and the ch2 connector is to send data to a slave one. I assume that the two channels on each connectors are outputting the same data to replicate the same PWM on both drivers.
[image]

I will try to get more and better logic analyzer screenshots!

Comment: RJ11 is a connector style, there are a lot of different "protocols" that can use that connector.

Comment: I am already aware of that. I am trying to identify the protocol on this specific device using a RJ11.

Comment: I think the point of @RonBeyer's comment is that perhaps you could have chosen a more appropriate title for your question, since the type of connector is not relevant.

Comment: I believe that when rj11 is used on phone lines, there are 2 pairs of signals. Since we seem to see 2 pairs of signal on the logic analyzer, I though it would help to mention it.

Comment: No, a conventional telephone line has one pair of wires.

Comment: My mistake, I have a RJ14 cable, not a RJ11. The RJ14 has two pair for two potential telephone lines

Comment: It's definitely not DALI. Pretty hard to tell from that screenshot, though. You'd need to provide a more detailed trace with a visible timebase, and perhaps some information about what the device was doing at the time of capture.

Comment: The logic capture might be misleading. If we step back and look at the context, would a simple device that needs to convey dimming information really use a strange protocol that requires 25 MHz over phone cables? Likely a problem in capture. Also, RJ11 and RJ14 are not connectors, they are intefaces which use specific 4p and 6p modular connectors.

Comment: Probably proprietary, could you acquire more sample at different settings?

Comment: It is possible the electrical interface is such that you never see anything unless the output is actually connected to another input. It might be open collector output and the input of next device acts as the supply current path. The 32768 samples at 25 MHz cover 1.3 milliseconds only, too quick for any protocol adequate for dimming.

Comment: Two identical data lines look suspicious. How did you connect the analyzer ground? Was the dimming unit connected during the measurement? You can use a scope instead of a logic analyzer to be more sure of the signal shape. Turning the knob while looking at the scope will tell where the bits are.

Comment: Im trying to reverse engineer the same thing. I have a RJ-14 6 wire connector going to the lights and trying to figure out how to hook it up to a Raspberry Pi. Have you had any luck?